# Pointer Issues "cannot instantiate abstract class"

Tags: c++

Doing a programming homework assignment and I am having some trouble with pointers. I'm not too sure what the issue is.

I have looked around and found a few solved issues but I can't seem to figure out how to implement the fixes in my own code. (noob)

in my main I call:

```
MotherShip* m1 = new MotherShip(5, 6);
```

I am getting the error "cannot instantiate abstract class" with this.

MotherShip.h:

```
#include "SpaceShip.h"

class MotherShip : public SpaceShip 
{
public:
    int capacity;

    MotherShip();
    MotherShip(int x, int y, int cap);
    MotherShip(const MotherShip& ms);

    void print();
};
```

MotherShip.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MotherShip.h"

MotherShip::MotherShip() 
{

}

MotherShip::MotherShip(int x, int y, int cap) 
{

}

MotherShip::MotherShip(const MotherShip& ms) 
{

}

void MotherShip::print() 
{

}
```

Here is my full main (I don't think it's important here so I thought I'd just pastie it)

http://pastie.org/pastes/8429256/text

Comment: Oh I should note that I shouldn't edit the main.cpp
(it is the testing code we have been given)

Comment: (a) What is the error you are receiving, and (b) have you got include guards?

Comment: There is no constructor that takes two ints as arguments

Comment: Why do you need to define custom copy constructor?

Comment: Please show implementation and header of `SpaceShip` class. This error hints at mistakes in class inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing two arguments to your class constructor, however you have not defined a constructor that takes two arguments.

One solution would be:

```
MotherShip* m1 = new MotherShip(5, 6, 7 /* passing third argument */);
```

Another solution is defining a constructor to take two arguments:

```
MotherShip(int x, int y);
```

Comment: I have edited the MotherShip constructor from "MotherShip();" to "MotherShip(int x, int y);"

in the cpp file I edited "MotherShip::MotherShip()" to "MotherShip::MotherShip(int x, int y)"

With these changes, I am still getting the same "cannot instantiate abstract class" errors. These are likely issues I would have had once I fixed the issue I'm asking about. I want to fix my current issue before anything else.


I am pretty sure the absence of a third parameter in my main.cpp is meant to assume that cap = 0 (I should refrain from editing the testing code in my main.cpp)

Answer (score 0):

you must set the cap parameter as your constructor requires it.

There's no constructor that takes two ints!
Use the default value in your declaration

```
MotherShip(int x, int y, int cap = 123);
```

or, as an alternative, declare and define another constructor that takes two ints:

```
MotherShip(int x, int y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be guessed without looking. `abstract class` in C++ is implemented by adding a pure virtual function.

You sure have a pure virtual function in your base class `SpaceShip` which you need to override in `MotherShip`. Or else `MotherShip` too becomes `abstract` and cannot be instantiated.

```
class SpaceShip
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0; //override this with some implementation in MotherShip
};
```